# How to set action (calling method) in own option in "More" option list?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

Odoo v8
I created submenu in "More" list in view. When I click on it, I see a form, which is used to ceating new record in this model. Is it possible to call some method instead of that when I choose this option?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using server action.

For example if you want to call method from more options in sale order

First you have to create server action.

**Server Action**

```
<record id="action_server_test_1" model="ir.actions.server">
            <field name="name">Test Action</field>
            <field name="condition">True</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
self.method_in_sale_order(cr,uid,context.get('active_id'))
        </field>
</record>
```

Then you need a menu to call this server action from more options.

You create it by using ir.values like this.

**ir.values Record**

```
<record model="ir.values" id="ir_values_sale_order">
      <field name="key2" eval="'client_action_multi'"/>
      <field name="model" eval="'sale.order'"/>
      <field name="name">Call Method</field>
      <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%action_server_test_1"/>
</record>
```

Now you have the menu so, click on it and you can call any method into the  `sale.order` model like on one i called is `method_in_sale_order()`

I hope this will work for you.